# How to call routes in a controller java play?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm writing an app with Java play OAuth2. When I was went through on a sample code([code](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaOAuth)), It has a line,

```
String url = routes.Twitter.auth().absoluteURL(request());
```

`Twitter` is a class and solve the compile error issue on this line. How may I call the routes like this in a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's reverse routing and syntax is valid, so if you have compile error at this point that means that you probably didn't add valid route declaration for your action within the `/conf/routes` file

Comment: Can you give a little demonstration, how may i define it. In this example it's like `Twitter`. It breaks the convention right?